How can a zombie process hold resources?
Wikipedia states the following on zombie processes:

However, zombies can also hold buffers open, consuming memory. Zombies can hold handles to file descriptors, which prevents the space for those files from being available to the filesystem.

How? What "buffers" can a zombie process hold (except for an entry in kernel process table)? How can a zombie hold a file descriptor?
I know that Linux closes all file descriptors when a process terminates. A zombie process is terminated. How can a zombie process still hold resources on Linux? It may be true for other operating systems, which may be not close all file descriptors. Is it possible to leak resources on Linux with zombie processes?
I tried some variations to try to reproduce:
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    switch (fork()) {
    case -1:
        _Exit(2);
    case 0:
        open("/dev/zero", O_RDONLY);
        _Exit(1);
    default:
        sleep(20);
        _Exit(1);
    }
}

Altough, it is a zombie:
$ ps aux | grep a.out
kamil      63844  0.0  0.0   2348   992 pts/1    S+   13:12   0:00 ./a.out
kamil      63845  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/1    Z+   13:12   0:00 [a.out] <defunct>
kamil      63862  0.0  0.0   9492  4436 pts/2    S+   13:13   0:00 grep a.out

I see nothing in lsof /dev/zero. How to write a program which produces a zombie that leaks resources on Linux?
According to man pages, _Exit or _exit https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html closes all file descriptors. In strace, I only see exit_group, no close. Are there other ways of process termination that result in unclosed file descriptors?

A zombie consumes a slot in the process table.  Whether that constitutes "holding a buffer open" is a question of semantics.  The wording is poor.

That is clear, and for the prupose of this question, that doesn't count,.

The passage you quote isn't about Linux specifically, but zombie processes in general. It may well be that you can't leak resources via zombies in Linux specifically.
